# Http request error 500 only on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, internal-server-error, http-error

I'm working with a webserver that works fine on android and browsers only.

On iOS I receive error 500 (internal server error)

Are there any params I should add to the request header?

```
 (void) weatherWS:(WSManagerDelegate*)delegate withUserId:(NSString*)userId withCurrentLanguage:(NSString*)currentLanguage{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_urlString];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestSuccessCallBack:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailedCallBack:)];
    int tag = [self _getRequestTag];
    if (delegate) {
        [_delegatesDictionary setObject:delegate forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",tag]];
    }
    [request setTag:tag];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setTimeOutSeconds:60];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];

}
```

the `request.responseStatusCode` is always 500 (internal sever error)

Comment: there should be some logs on your server.

Comment: Are you using query string parameters ?

Comment: i don't have access to server's log

Comment: Also isn't ASIHTTPRequest very outdated ?

Comment: @Carlos487 actually yes i have some parametre to send

Comment: Maybe they are not URL encoded, maybe the other platforms do it automatically. Be aware of using %, &, = and other symbols or use a URL encoding function before sending them

Comment: If you only control the clients (and not the web server) then capture the HTTP traffic sent from the working Android client and compare it to what your iOS client is sending.  You might have to route through an HTTP proxy to capture both HTTP requests.

Comment: @Jkmn it isn't supported anymore so yes it is outdated and I would recommend AFNetorking (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/) instead, but that doesn't mean others don't still use it. I have an app that still uses it because there isn't anything wrong with it and it's more hassle then its worth to change over. I really don't think that this issue is caused by them using `ASIHttpRequest`.

Comment: @Carlos487 i rechecked and i don't think it's a probleme of URL encoding, cause i use the same methode with other webservices and it works fine.

Comment: Can you use fiddler or any proxy to see the request that is traveling to the wire and compare android and ios HTTP requests.

Comment: Does the same happen with simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i don't know why but adding 
`[ASIHTTPRequest setSessionCookies:nil];` 
makes it works!! the weird part is the server did't send any cookies !!